# How to find the index of a dropdown for the given text

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I find the index of a dropdown for a given value using jQuery?

Here is my dropdown with three values:

1. admin
2. mananger
3. employee

I'm able to get the index of the selected value like below

```
var index = $("#mydropdown").find("option:selected").val();
```

But I need to know the index of manager by passing manager as an argument to a jQuery function to get the index

I tried like this but it's not working

```
var index = $("#mydropdown").find("manager").val();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `:contains` or `.filter()`. I personally prefer `.filter()`:

```
var index = $("#mydropdown").find(":contains(manager)").val();
//Or
var index = $("#mydropdown").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "manager";
}).val();
```

This assume your drop down look like this :

```
<select>
    <option value="1">admin</option>
    <option value="2">manager</option>
    <option value="3">employee</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need something like this:

**js**

```
$("select option[value='manager']").index()
```

**html**

```
<select>
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
    <option value="manager">mananger</option>
    <option value="employee">employee</option>
</select>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4dFDH/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you need to force the user to make a selection use an empty option and then have code check for a value ='0' or an index of zero respectively.  *I have added an empty option in both implementations below for this purpose.*

**Implementation #1:**

```
function optionchanged()
{
    var i = $("#option1").val();
    var t = $("#option1 option:selected").text();
    console.log("The Index of option selected is: " + i);
    console.log("The Text of option selected is: " + t);
}
```

Assign index to value property in each option allows you greater control over the value returned.

```
<select id="option1" onchange="optionchanged();">
    <option value="0"></option>  
    <option value="1">Admin</option>
    <option value="2">Manager</option>
    <option value="3">Employee</option>
</select>
```

The Console Output looks like this:

Selecting 'Admin' produces:
The Index of option selected is: 1 
The Text of option selected is: Admin

Selecting 'Employee' produces:
The Index of option selected is: 3 
The Text of option selected is: Employee

**Implementation #2:**

If you don't want to add the index to value you can reference the index directly in jQuery like this:

```
function optionchanged()
{
    //var i = $("#option1 ").val();
    var i = $("#option1 option:selected").index();
    var t = $("#option1 option:selected").text();
    console.log("The Index of option selected is: " + i);
    console.log("The Text of option selected is: " + t);
    //alert("Value of option 1 is: " + index);
}


<select id="option1" onchange="optionchanged();">
    <option></option>
    <option>Admin</option>
    <option>Manager</option>
    <option>Employee</option>
</select>
```

The console output will look the same as above.